# Unhandled exception information in VS with MonoAndroid

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, mono, opengl-es-2.0, xamarin.android

I'm trying to play with Android emulator and VS.

I've downloaded the GLTriangle20 example from the Mono official site and tried to run it. However it fell at CreateFrameBuffer();
Visual Studio highlights this line with green, pauses the debagger but doesn't show any information about this exception.

I even tried to wrap this line into try/catch, but it doesn't catch anything. VS just stops on that line and says nothing except green highlight. It looks like that:[image: Strange thing]

I downloaded JDK, Mono, and Android SDK yesterday, so all these tools are fresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running without debugging (Ctrl-F5) and check the Android log for the exception:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/

Comment: When I press Ctrl-F5 it doesn't run at all. VS asks for emulator, I select it, then it checks if application has changes and after that just exits to VS.

Comment: The app is running, crashing, and disappearing.  You need to check the Debug Log for the reason that it crashed.

Comment: Really! Thanks) It says Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find a framebuffer for OpenGL ES 2.0     However is it ok so in debug mode I can't read exception info? It is very uncomfortable to read logs every time

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution to add a handler to the app unhandled event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32755558/1282432

Only thing I don't like about it is it needs to be put into every activity - or you create a base class - which I can't do because I'm using MVVMCross......

It would be nice if there was ONE application.unhandledexception, but I haven't found it yet...