# Exceptions when using Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012

I recently started to learn mobile development using Xamarin Android. I am using VS 2012. I noticed that when I open an android project that all exceptions under Debug -> Exceptions are unchecked. I thought that is the reason that exceptions thrown in code are not shown in a way to which I am used to from desktop development. When I checked the exceptions in Debug->Exceptions window and tried to deploy the solution to the emulator it failed - there were no errors but the application does not start on the emulator.

So my question is: Is that normal behavior when developing for Android using VS 2012 or VS 2010 and the emulator? Is there any way to see the thrown exceptions in a 'normal way' not just in output window. Would that change if I used an actual Android device for debugging?

Answer (score 5):

> Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The code execution in visual studio does break, but instad of a standard window used to explore the exception which I get when programming for desktop, the window contains only the name of the thrown exception, a checkbox to disable the code break when this type of exception is thrown and Break, Continue and Ignore buttons. But I can not explore the actual exception in a way available when programming for desktop.

In the `Debug --> Exceptions` dialog box, if you click the `Thrown` checkbox for `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` you will get a more meaningful description of the exception to be resolved.

[image]

**Obviously the other big thing is clicking the Break button and seeing what is on the call stack.**

Answer (score 5):

My Answer Is *NO*

Why?

> There is one important thing you have to understand about the nature
>   of an Unhandled exception in Android, there isn't one.... in Android
>   it's an Uncaught exception which means you can't "handle" it or
>   recover from it like you maybe would in a .Net environment.
>
> Xamarin(Mono) internally "handles" those uncaught exceptions by
>   surrounding literally everything with try-catch and raising the
>   Unhandled event but that is besides the point. It is also discouraged
>   to interact with the UI as well for various reasons.
>
> Theoretically there are several "workarounds" for displaying a dialog
>   to the user or restarting the app, none of which I'd recommend on
>   doing. Instead you should surround sensitive areas with try-catch
>   clauses to handle expected exceptions, as for the unexpected one's
>   just use an exception reporting component and update your app after
>   analyzing the reported exceptions

*Explation [From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118892/struggling-to-understand-xamarin-exception-handling)*

also you could catch the  unhadled exception from app Like this

*Create a base activity like name **ErrorActivity***

*look at this example*

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
        //register error handlers
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ErrorHandler.CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
                    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += ErrorHandler.TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
  }
```

In error handler class

```
public static class ErrorHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Tasks the scheduler on unobserved task exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs">
        ///     The <see cref="UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs" /> instance containing
        ///     the event data.
        /// </param>
        public static void TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException(object sender,
            UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs)
        {
            var newExc = new Exception("TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException",
                unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs.Exception);
            LogUnhandledException(newExc);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Currents the domain on unhandled exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="unhandledExceptionEventArgs">
        ///     The <see cref="UnhandledExceptionEventArgs" /> instance containing the event
        ///     data.
        /// </param>
        public static void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender,
            UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        {
            var newExc = new Exception("CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException",
                unhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject as Exception);
            LogUnhandledException(newExc);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Logs the unhandled exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="exception">The exception.</param>
        internal static void LogUnhandledException(Exception exception)
        {
            try
            {
                string error =
                    $"Exception Caught:{DateTime.Now:F} The Error Message IS {exception.Message}\n\r full stack trace is {exception.ToString()} ";
#if DEBUG
                const string errorFileName = "errorlog.txt";
                var libraryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                // iOS: Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources
                var errorFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(libraryPath, errorFileName);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(errorFilePath, error);
                Android.Util.Log.Error("Crash Report error not handled", ex.ToString());
    #else
                    // Log to Android Device Logging.
                    Android.Util.Log.Error("Crash Report", error);
    #endif
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Android.Util.Log.Error("Crash Report error not handled", ex.ToString());
                    // just suppress any error logging exceptions
                }
            }
        }
```

Now you could inherit the all activitys from ErrorActivity like this

```
Public class Fooactivity:ErrorActivity
{
}
```

Now you can handled the error in app..So you get the error log from log File.. or android device logging monitor..Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Xamarin as well.  The simple answer is no this is not what you should expect.

If I get an exception when the application is running on the device it breaks in Visual Studio. Best bet is to contact Xamarin direct or go on there forums.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The code execution in visual studio does break, but instad of a standard window used to explore the exception which I get when programming for desktop, the window contains only the name of the thrown exception, a checkbox to disable the code break when this type of exception is thrown and Break, Continue and Ignore buttons. But I can not explore the actual exception in a way available when programming for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to dig into Unhandled exception:

Proceed following:

1. Catch event `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`
2. If you look closely, you will see that its basically somehow translated Java.Lang.Runtime exception so if you examine the `ExceptionObject` property it should give you very clear message what is wrong with app. In my case it gave me very clear message that I am not calling base `OnDestroyView` in my `Fragment`