# Struggling to understand Xamarin exception handling

Tags: c#, android, mobile, mono, xamarin

I have been crawling the Internet for quite a long time in hope of a solution, and I've come across a number of answers, but none of these seem to achieve what I want.

I'm trying to handle exceptions without causing the app to crash. Rather than the app simply exiting, I would rather capture the exception, present the user with a more user-friendly error (perhaps a messagebox warning) and allow them to continue operation in the app.

Is it possible to stop the app from bailing out?

The way I'm currently attempting to catch this is like the following:

```
public class Login : Activity
{
    int count = 1;
    Session mySession;

   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += HandleAndroidException;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);


            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Login);
            string accountCode = Resource.Id.AccountCode.ToString();
            string password = Resource.Id.Password.ToString();

            // button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                    throw new Exception("LETS THROW A RANDOM EXCEPTION");

            };

    }


    void HandleAndroidException(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Error("INTERNAL DEBUG", "PLEASE HANDLE MY EXCEPTION!");
        e.Handled = true;
        System.Console.Write("YOU'VE JUST BEEN HANDLED!");
    }
}
```

As you can see I am throwing a general exception and attempting to catch this with an UnhandledExceptionRaiser. I used this as a reference: http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=E%3AAndroid.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser

I am able to find my message in the "Android Device Logging" tool, however it is being triggered AFTER an unhandled exception error occurs. I think this means something inside of Xamarin is having first crack at the exception and falling over. Surely there has to be a way of stopping this??

I have seen countless examples online where people have been asking similar questions and there has been no clear solution. Some people have offered some solutions, but these don't actually do what I had anticipated.

It is literally mind boggling to me if this cannot be done.

This is my first time using Xamarin and also my first time developing a mobile app so I apologise if I'm being ignorant about anything.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 12):

There is one important thing you have to understand about the nature of an `Unhandled` exception in Android, there isn't one.... in Android framework which uses Java it's an `Uncaught` exception which means you can't "handle" it or recover from it like you maybe would in a .Net environment. Xamarin(Mono) internally "handles" those uncaught exceptions by surrounding literally everything with try-catch and raising the Unhandled event but that is besides the point. It is also discouraged to interact with the UI as well for various reasons.
Theoretically there are several "workarounds" for displaying a dialog to the user or restarting the app, none of which I'd recommend on doing. Instead you should surround sensitive areas with try-catch clauses to handle expected exceptions, as for the unexpected one's just use an exception reporting component and update your app after analyzing the reported exceptions.

Also, I would move the event subscription to the `Application` class but that is a personal preference.
Like so:

```
public class YourAppClass : Application
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += HandleAndroidException;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Appreciate the response. Could you give me a recommendation or two for some reporting components? Could you spare a minute to also elaborate on using the Application class and the basic class structure you'd throughout the app?

thanks!

Comment: The components are HockeyApp and Raygun (are the ones I worked with).  http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/hockeyappandroid
https://components.xamarin.com/view/raygun4net
And as for the Application class see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex I'll be sure to check those out. So is the general concept to create one Application class and then each activity implements the application class? Sorry - new to Xamarin/mobile dev!

Comment: Oh god no :) I'd suggest you don't take my comment about the Application class to literally, your approach is fine as well I just feel that having it centralized in **one** class is more intuitive for me. As to your question you implement the Application class only once in a separate class, your activities are not affected by it, you keep inheriting from your base class as you have done so far. Here is some reading material on the Application class: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android

Comment: Is there any literature on the Xamarin website which explicitly states you cannot handle these "uncaught" exceptions? I'm not entirely sure how you could build a robust app if unable to recover from certain exceptions. What does Xamarin specifically recommend you do? I haven't really been able to find much on the Xamarin website about this.

Comment: This only for monoAndroid, Is their any way to handle the same situation can be handel in PCL project ?

Comment: So it is a flaw in the xamarin platform. To my mind there is no such thing as an unexpected exception. All exceptions are unexpected or they would be part of the main flow. Any software app, on any platform should have the ability to intercept any scenario and handle it as it sees fit. If the app is unstable and must be shut down then the app should be able to convey that message and possibly provide support information. If the platform does not offer this then it's a design flaw/bug and workarounds should be applied.

Comment: Adding to what @ComeIn said, even if unhandled exceptions are thrown, we, as developers, should have means to at least figure out what is the problem and try to avoid it. As of now, exceptions are thrown from various points, and are essencially uncaught even by the event provided.