# How can I make my Xamarin app send an email whenever an error occurs?

Tags: c#, email, xamarin, exception

My Xamarin app's release version is being tested by a non-developer, which sometimes means the tester has trouble communicating to me the details of bugs they encounter.

I'd like to implement some code that will execute whenever a crash or error occurs, and send an email to my address with the error information to help my debugging. I've written an email method (see below) but I'd like to know how I can call it whenever an unhandled exception is thrown rather than wrapping every single possible method in a try-catch.

```
public static void Email(string htmlString)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("email here");
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("other email here"));
                msg.Subject = "Error Report";
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Body = htmlString;
                smtp.Port = 1234;
                smtp.Host = "smtp here";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password");
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: use a crash reporting too like appcenter.ms - they are much more robust than anything you'll write yourself

Comment: AppCenter does look useful but I'm not looking for a paid solution, thanks.

Comment: The base tiers are free.  If you insist on doing it yourself, search on global exception handlers, there are many examples

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to catch errors in Xamarin apps is by using a try/catch block. Try/catch is easy to get.

You could do something like below.

```
private void Send_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            .......
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Email(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
    public static void Email(string htmlString)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("email here");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("other email here"));
        msg.Subject = "Error Report";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Body = htmlString;
        smtp.Port = 1234;
        smtp.Host = "smtp here";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password");
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Send(msg);        
    }
```

> Xamarin(Mono) internally "handles" those uncaught exceptions by surrounding literally everything with try-catch and raising the Unhandled event.

Explanation from the thread. [Struggling to understand Xamarin exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118892/struggling-to-understand-xamarin-exception-handling)

You could check the link. It provides a way to get the error log from log File.
[Exceptions when using Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234155/exceptions-when-using-xamarin-android)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As outlined in my answer, I'm looking for a global solution for any time an error occurs, implementing try-catch in every single method that could possibly cause an exception is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You could try to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` to catch the Unhandled exceptions. Please check the blog.https://peterno.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/unhandled-exception-handling-in-ios-and-android-with-xamarin/