# Visual studio community 2015 An unhandled exception occured

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

It prompts me to enter break mode and the only text that is displayed in that window and output is "An unhandled exception occured." (doesn't even show what line) how can I view the exception details?

Comment: is this when you run an app? did you run it it debug mode?

Comment: @BugFinder Yes to both

Comment: then that does seem odd, it could be that the exception is being generated outside your code in something thats in an external library etc.. its not easy to tell.  Debug, step through and find out where you are when its triggered

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32754919/495455 also you do have the Tools -> Options -> Debug -> Exception Assistant turned on?

Comment: It's already turned on. I think it has something to do with a reference like BugFinder suggests.